# Reading Serial number of RaspberryPi device by PHP

Tags: php, shell, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

For a project I would like to check the identity of a raspberry Pi device.
so I can use that identity to register to the system.

because only raspberry Pi devices may work my webservice.

I tested this code and when I run it locally on my raspberry it works.
but when I put this script online it does not do anything.. I've even set the file permission even to 777 for sure..

What did I missed here? some privacy issues? I really need that unique serial

Code:

```
$output = shell_exec('cat /proc/cpuinfo');
$find = 'Serial';
$pos = strpos($output, $find);

$serial = substr($output, $pos+9, 17); // returns "00000000f8df2b8d
```

Comment: You are not checking the serial number of the device that is visiting your site, but the serial number of the server that is running the script. You would need to run a client-site script (javascript) to get information about the device that is requesting the information but I doubt that the serial number would be available to javascript.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense!  I also want to execute a script (on the server) to blink some lights attached to the raspberry device.  and I've build an API for devices in the future..    aw..